# how sessions disabled by .htaccess

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, session, mod-rewrite

I am using the wordpress for my website, i create sub domain and use some php code for it,it works good.

the problem is this:
when i use the .htaccess for wordpress, my php code can not store the sessions.

**Please help me and tell me which line of the .htaccess removes the sessions**

 here is my .htaccess content:

```
# BEGIN iThemes Security - Do not modify or remove this line
# iThemes Security Config Details: 2
# Protect System Files - Security > Settings > System Tweaks > System Files
<files .htaccess>
    <IfModule mod_litespeed.c>
        Order allow,deny
        Deny from all
    </IfModule>
</files>
<files readme.html>
    <IfModule mod_litespeed.c>
        Order allow,deny
        Deny from all
    </IfModule>
</files>
<files readme.txt>
    <IfModule mod_litespeed.c>
        Order allow,deny
        Deny from all
    </IfModule>
</files>
<files install.php>
    <IfModule mod_litespeed.c>
        Order allow,deny
        Deny from all
    </IfModule>
</files>
<files wp-config.php>
    <IfModule mod_litespeed.c>
        Order allow,deny
        Deny from all
    </IfModule>
</files>

# Disable Directory Browsing - Security > Settings > System Tweaks > Directory Browsing
Options -Indexes

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Protect System Files - Security > Settings > System Tweaks > System Files
    RewriteRule ^wp-admin/includes/ - [F]
    RewriteRule !^wp-includes/ - [S=3]
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !^(.*)wp-includes/ms-files.php
    RewriteRule ^wp-includes/[^/]+\.php$ - [F]
    RewriteRule ^wp-includes/js/tinymce/langs/.+\.php - [F]
    RewriteRule ^wp-includes/theme-compat/ - [F]

    # Disable PHP in Uploads - Security > Settings > System Tweaks > Uploads
    RewriteRule ^wp\-content/uploads/.*\.(?:php[1-6]?|pht|phtml?)$ - [NC,F]

    # Filter Request Methods - Security > Settings > System Tweaks > Request Methods
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(TRACE|DELETE|TRACK) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^.* - [F]

    # Filter Suspicious Query Strings in the URL - Security > Settings > System Tweaks > Suspicious Query Strings
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \.\.\/ [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*\.(bash|git|hg|log|svn|swp|cvs) [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} etc/passwd [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} boot\.ini [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ftp\:  [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} http\:  [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} https\:  [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\<|%3C).*script.*(\>|%3E) [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} mosConfig_[a-zA-Z_]{1,21}(=|%3D) [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode.*\(.*\) [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(%24&x).* [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(127\.0).* [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(globals|encode|localhost|loopback).* [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(request|concat|insert|union|declare).* [NC]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^loggedout=true
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^action=jetpack-sso
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^action=rp
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*wordpress_logged_in_.*$
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://maps\.googleapis\.com(.*)$
    RewriteRule ^.* - [F]
</IfModule>

# Disable XML-RPC - Security > Settings > WordPress Tweaks > XML-RPC
<files xmlrpc.php>
    <IfModule mod_litespeed.c>
        Order allow,deny
        Deny from all
    </IfModule>
</files>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Reduce Comment Spam - Security > Settings > WordPress Tweaks > Comment Spam
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /wp-comments-post\.php$
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^$ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://(([^/]+\.)?ashrafiprint\.com|jetpack\.wordpress\.com/jetpack-comment)(/|$) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^.* - [F]
</IfModule>

# Enable HackRepair.com's blacklist feature - Security > Settings > Banned Users > Default Blacklist
# Start HackRepair.com Blacklist
RewriteEngine on
# Start Abuse Agent Blocking
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Mozilla.*Indy" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Mozilla.*NEWT" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^$" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Maxthon$" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^SeaMonkey$" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Acunetix" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^binlar" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^BlackWidow" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Bolt 0" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^BOT for JCE" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Bot mailto\:craftbot@yahoo\.com" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^casper" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^checkprivacy" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^ChinaClaw" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^clshttp" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^cmsworldmap" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^comodo" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Custo" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Default Browser 0" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^diavol" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^DIIbot" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^DISCo" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^dotbot" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Download Demon" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^eCatch" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^EirGrabber" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^EmailCollector" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^EmailSiphon" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^EmailWolf" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Express WebPictures" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^extract" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^ExtractorPro" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^EyeNetIE" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^feedfinder" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^FHscan" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^FlashGet" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^flicky" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^g00g1e" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^GetRight" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^GetWeb\!" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Go\!Zilla" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Go\-Ahead\-Got\-It" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^grab" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^GrabNet" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Grafula" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^harvest" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^HMView" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^ia_archiver" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Image Stripper" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Image Sucker" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^InterGET" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Internet Ninja" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^InternetSeer\.com" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^jakarta" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Java" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^JetCar" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^JOC Web Spider" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^kanagawa" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^kmccrew" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^larbin" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^LeechFTP" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^libwww" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Mass Downloader" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^microsoft\.url" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^MIDown tool" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^miner" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Mister PiX" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^MSFrontPage" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Navroad" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^NearSite" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Net Vampire" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^NetAnts" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^NetSpider" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^NetZIP" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^nutch" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Octopus" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Offline Explorer" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Offline Navigator" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^PageGrabber" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Papa Foto" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^pavuk" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^pcBrowser" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^PeoplePal" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^planetwork" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^psbot" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^purebot" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^pycurl" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^RealDownload" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^ReGet" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Rippers 0" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^sitecheck\.internetseer\.com" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^SiteSnagger" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^skygrid" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^SmartDownload" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^sucker" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^SuperBot" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^SuperHTTP" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Surfbot" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^tAkeOut" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Teleport Pro" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Toata dragostea mea pentru diavola" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^turnit" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^vikspider" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^VoidEYE" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Web Image Collector" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Web Sucker" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^WebAuto" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^WebBandit" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^WebCopier" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^WebFetch" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^WebGo IS" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^WebLeacher" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^WebReaper" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^WebSauger" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Website eXtractor" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Website Quester" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^WebStripper" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^WebWhacker" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^WebZIP" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Wget" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Widow" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^WPScan" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^WWW\-Mechanize" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^WWWOFFLE" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Xaldon WebSpider" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Zeus" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^zmeu" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "360Spider" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "AhrefsBot" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "CazoodleBot" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "discobot" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "EasouSpider" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "ecxi" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "GT\:\:WWW" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "heritrix" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "HTTP\:\:Lite" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "HTTrack" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "ia_archiver" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "id\-search" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "IDBot" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "Indy Library" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "IRLbot" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "ISC Systems iRc Search 2\.1" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "LinksCrawler" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "LinksManager\.com_bot" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "linkwalker" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "lwp\-trivial" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "MFC_Tear_Sample" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "Microsoft URL Control" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "Missigua Locator" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "MJ12bot" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "panscient\.com" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "PECL\:\:HTTP" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "PHPCrawl" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "PleaseCrawl" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "SBIder" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "SearchmetricsBot" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "SeznamBot" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "Snoopy" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "Steeler" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "URI\:\:Fetch" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "urllib" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "Web Sucker" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "webalta" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "WebCollage" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "Wells Search II" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "WEP Search" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "XoviBot" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "YisouSpider" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "zermelo" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "ZyBorg" [NC,OR]
# End Abuse Agent Blocking
# Start Abuse HTTP Referrer Blocking
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} "^https?://(?:[^/]+\.)?semalt\.com" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} "^https?://(?:[^/]+\.)?kambasoft\.com" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} "^https?://(?:[^/]+\.)?savetubevideo\.com" [NC]
# End Abuse HTTP Referrer Blocking
RewriteRule ^.* - [F,L]
# End HackRepair.com Blacklist, http://pastebin.com/u/hackrepair

# Enable the hide backend feature - Security > Settings > Hide Login Area > Hide Backend
RewriteRule ^(/)?my_rule/?$ /wp-login.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(/)?wp-register-php/?$ /wplogin?action=register [QSA,L]
# END iThemes Security - Do not modify or remove this line

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: For a start... How are you handling sessions? Cookies? If so, what domain are you setting the cookie for? Are you using Https? Are your cookies being set with the Https-only flag?

Comment: I don't use https, i dont use Cookies, I use the session like this:`session_start();$_SESSION['name']="ali"`

Comment: Sessions are user-specific and the user needs to know their session ID for them to work. This is _usually_ done by setting a cookie. It's possible to preserve the session Id without cookies by passing it around at the end of every link but that's rarer and more error-prone. By default, wordpress uses cookies: https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Cookies . My guess would be that you're configuring the cookies to be for `www.example.com` instead of `example.com`, so they're not being sent by the browser to subdomains, but there are multiple other possibilities. Make sure... (cont)

Comment: ... your site url is set correctly in the wordpress config... https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to delete each line and test the result, maybe you can success